# SaveAs Edited Word Document VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I got an error trying to save my modified word document as pdf or doc:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Mütabakat Kontrol.

```
objWordApp = New Word.Application

Dim objDoc As Word.Document

objWordApp.Documents.Open(dosyaword)
objDoc = objWordApp.ActiveDocument

objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="&%/FIRMA_ADI\%&", _
  ReplaceWith:=ListBox9.Items(0).ToString, _
  Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="&%/BAKIYE\%&", _
  ReplaceWith:=ListBox12.Items(0).ToString & parabirimi, _
  Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="&%/TARIH\%&", _
  ReplaceWith:=ListBox13.Items(0).ToString, _
  Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
While objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", _
    Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
    objDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", ReplaceWith:=" ", _
        Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, _
        Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
End While

objWordApp.Documents.Item(1).SaveAsQuickStyleSet(Application.StartupPath
  & "\PDF\" & ListBox8.Items(0).ToString & ".doc")

objWordApp.Documents.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
objWordApp.Quit()
objWordApp = Nothing
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working? If you get an exception what is its type and message? If you don't get an exception how do you know it isn't working? What debugging steps have you taken?

Comment: Sorry i forgot.
It is my exception: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Mütabakat Kontrol.exe

Comment: What version of word are you referencing?